# SAP S4HANA timeout in Mulesoft

Tags: connection, mule, mule-studio, mulesoft, mule-esb

Need small help on SAP S4HANA timeout error.  While testing connecting using 'Test Connection' on SAP S4HANA connector in Mulesoft getting time out error.

Attached screenshot to understand the issue clearly.

Please help to provide solution on this.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWC1J.png)

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation of the S/4HANA SOAP Connector there is a connection timeout [parameter in the connector's configuration](https://docs.mulesoft.com/sap-s4hana-soap-connector/2.2/sap-s4hana-soap-connector-reference#parameters):

> Connection timeout Number Connection timeout for the request

Comment: I have configured Connection timeout to 90 Seconds even though getting Timeout exception

Comment: 180 seconds also configured even though getting Timeout exception.  If I try to connect through postman using same host, port, username and pwd by providing resource and query parameters then getting response. But when I try to connect through Mulesoft Anypoint studio using 'Test Connection' just to test the connection then getting timeout.  If I get the connection success then as 2nd step I will configure resource and query parameters to connect and get the response based on query parameters.

Comment: we tried with other way by configuring in S/4HANA